# How can I call a function with a dynamic amount of arguments?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I have an array and I need to pass each element of the array as parameters to a function.

Say:

```
$var = array("var2","var3","var4");
//Pass each element as a new parameter to a function
call_to_function ($var2, $var3, $var4);

//However, if the number of array element change it can be
$var = array("var2","var3");
call_to_function ($var2,$var3);
```

The problem here is, how to build dynamic number of parameters and call the function.

**Use:**
PHP Function [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), takes multiple parameters. And I need to derive the parameters from an arrray.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: So you want to call `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` with this array?

Comment: Maybe `call_user_func_array`(http://php.net/call_user_func_array) with `func_num_args` and `func_get_args` ?

Comment: Assign a key to each value of the array. Then you can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to split the array into variables.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First you need to create an array with references to the corresponding variables. You can simply do this with a foreach loop like below:

```
foreach($var as $v) {
        $bindValues[] = &$$v; 
}
```

After this you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call the function to bind the variables. Here it depends if you use procedural or OOP style:

procedural:

```
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge([$stmt, $types], $bindValues));
```

OOP:

```
call_user_func_array([$stmt, "bind_param"], array_merge([$types], $bindValues));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval() to call the function with dynamic number of parameters.

```
// Construct the parameter string like "$var[0], $var[1], $var[2]"
$param_str = '';
foreach($var as $key => $val) {
    $param_str .= '$var['.$key.'],';
}
$param_str = rtrim($param_str, ',');

eval('call_to_function('.$param_str.');');
```

Usage of eval() is not considered good practice but if your are sure that your array keys $var are always integer (like in your example default keys) then this should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

`call_user_func_array()` is just for that:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $var);
```